# Ensuring an object is inherited from another in java

Tags: java, inheritance

How do I know if an object is inherited from another object ?

Let's say I have an abstract class A. How do I know if an object is an instance of a class inherited from A ?

```
boolean inherited = false;
for (Class c : instance.getClasses()) {
    if (c == A.class) {
        inherited = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Does this work ? It seems a bit heavy for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof` should work fine for this situation, but it does beg the question of why you're trying to do things this way, if perhaps there's a better more *OOP* solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: It works fine, thanks ! It's weird because an instance from an abstract class is impossible, but well, it work.

Comment: Well, this is checking for instanceof not for inheritance. i.e. Instanceof evaluates to true when checking an instance of class A against an interface I when A implements I. But A does not inherit from I.

Comment: @Klems: still, I'd like to know why you think you need to use this? What problem are you using this to solve?

Answer (score 2):

An `instanceof` an abstract class must also be an `instanceof` some class which extends that abstract class.  You cannot instantiate abstract classes, but you can instantiate objects of a class which extends it.

It may also help to realize that any object that you have created is an `instanceof Object`.  this is because `Object` is at the top of the hierarchy of the subclass relationship for instantiable classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check for inheritance:

```
ClassUtils.getAllSuperclasses(c.getClass()).contains(A.class);
```

`ClassUtils` is a utility class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).